# View Contents of Text File in browser from gae blobstore java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have text files stored in GAE Blobstore.
Now I want to read the contents of the file and view them in my browser, without actually downloading the file.

I am accessing the servlet by clicking on link on my HTML page which access the servlet.

I am serving the file with blobKey

```
    String blobKey = req.getParameter("blobKey");
    BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(blobKey);
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" +fileName +"\"");
    blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, resp);
```

But the above code is downloading the file instead by displaying it in a browser.
Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the line setting the Content-Disposition in the header, that should do the trick.